# How to: Pass sensitive values Between ASP.NET Web Pages?

Tags: c#

How to: Pass sensitive values Between ASP.NET Web Pages? (without first storing it in the database or using session variable).

```
page1.aspx --> page2.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodness there are a lot of answers. You could:

- Save it to the session
- Encrypt it and add it as an HTTP parameter
- Encrypt it and set a cookie
- Create an external WCF caching service (page 1 caches the data with a random GUID and passes the key to page 2)
- etc.

We may be able to give some further guidance if you gave us some more details regarding what type of data you are trying to pass.

Comment: what about passing a record between web pages? can it be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Session variable
- Encrypted cookie
- Static variable (very dangerous as it will be one for all intances...)